# Google API for Restaurants Places

Tags: google-places-api

I am having problems understanding the Google Places API. I am building an iPhone application with a nearby feature that allows the user to find restaurants located around the user's GPS. How can I obtain a Google API for this? Do I have to have one custom made how does this work? If I also wanted to create an API for points of interest how can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

There is a Google Places API for searching for nearby locations. The documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests

But I'm guessing you already found that. If you ask more specific questions, we can be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Im having a hard time understanding APIs. I think Ive got somewhat of a handle on it now. I am building an application using seattleclouds.com. How can I display the results I get back using the google API in an HTML format?

Comment: You'd need to tell me what programming language you're using.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Google place API , and if you want to display only specific type of places e.g restaurant in your cases you can use request object as shown in the code below

```
 var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    type: ['restaurant']
  };

 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
places.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

For more details on type filteration in google place API you can check the [Link on Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).
But nearby search taking only one type parameter, and it is only restaurants. Not food, not cafe, only restaurants, which Google API provides, if you are looking for the public catering establishments.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the Google Paces API should be active.

```js
function displayRestaurantAround() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.service.nearbySearch({
      location: currentUserPosition,
      radius: 5000,
      types: ['restaurant']
    }, (res) => {
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}
```